# Service Worker in iFrame

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, service-worker

I am trying to initialize a service worker inside an iframe. I understand that service workers have security restrictions when it comes to origin, but as I understand setting `base` should solve this issue.

```
<html>
   <base href="http://127.0.0.1:9090">
   <script>
     if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
        window.addEventListener('load', function() {
          navigator.serviceWorker.register('/sw.js').then(function(reg) {

            if(reg.installing) {
              console.log('Service worker installing');
            } else if(reg.waiting) {
              console.log('Service worker installed');
            } else if(reg.active) {
              console.log('Service worker active');
              console.log(self)
            }
          }).catch(function(error) {
            // registration failed
            console.log('Registration failed with ' + error);
          });
        });
      }
   </script>
```

Error:
`Registration failed with InvalidStateError: Failed to register a ServiceWorker: The document is in an invalid state.`

If I modify the base it complains that the origins are not the same, so service worker  is somewhat connected with base href. What am I missing here?

Thank you for your help

Comment: From my observation, you get the error `The document is in an invalid state.` when you try to register a service worker from an anonymous (dynamic) iframe.

Answer (score 5):

The `<base>` element does not change the origin of the document.  You can test this by logging `self.origin`.

What `<base>` does do, however, is change the base URL for resolving relative URLs.  In this case your service worker script is a relative URL.  So instead of being relative to `self.location` its relative to the new base.

This means if you give `<base>` a cross-origin URL then your service worker script will also be cross-origin.  This will trigger an error when you try to register it.

Comment: Is there a way to register a worker inside a blob or iframe? I am constructing a parent iframe which is then used to serve a website which may have multiple iframes. I am trying to avoid using any backend server so what I did was, I download and store the zip into indexdb (BrowserFS) and then created blobs, which I want to replace the files needed by the website (img.png -> blob:http://127.0.0.1:9090/dsdasdasdasd). For this I need to have service workers inside the iframe, so they map img.png to the blob file.

Comment: You can register a service worker in an iframe (unless there is some policy blocking the iframe from accessing storage/cookies/etc.)  The iframe must have a real origin, though.  So you cannot register a service worker in a sandboxed iframe.  In theory you should be able to register a service worker in an iframe with a blob URL, but that blob URL will inherit the origin from its creating context.  This case is not well tested, though, and I would not be surprised if its buggy.

Answer (score 3):

I will post my observations about the error `Failed to register a ServiceWorker: The document is in an invalid state.` since I could not find much information about the error.

When an iframe is added to the document dynamically, registering a service worker from that iframe will result in the above error. For example:

```
var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');

var html = 
`<head>
    <script src="./index.js" ></script>
</head>
<body>Foo</body>`;
document.body.appendChild(iframe);
iframe.contentWindow.document.open();
iframe.contentWindow.document.write(html);
iframe.contentWindow.document.close();
```

As opposed to having the iframe statically in the parent html, where service registration would work.

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>  
        <iframe>
            <html>
                <head>
                    <script src="./index.js"></script>
                </head>
                <body>
                    <h4>Foo</h4>
                </body>
            </html>
        </iframe>
    </body>
</html>
```

Service worker registration code is in index.js which looks like this:

```
if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
    navigator.serviceWorker.register('/sw.js')
    .then((reg) => {
        // registration worked
        console.log('Registration succeeded. Scope is ' + reg.scope);
    }).catch((error) => {
        // registration failed
        console.log('Registration failed with ' + error);
    });
}
```

The second case would work even with sandbox iframes provided the sandbox has `allow-same-origin` enabled.